# EDC machine crashes if I initialize a global variable

Tags: c, enums, global-variables, payment

I am working on [EDC machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_terminal) from Ingenico. I had defined an `enum` variables as shown below in a header file.

**global.h**

```
enum _MY_VARIABLES {
   _ONE, _TWO, _THREE
}
```

**file1.c:**

```
#include "global.h"
enum _MY_VARIABLES CurrentValue = -1; //Initializing global variable.
```

EDC crashes if I initialize the global variable, but works fine if I don't initialize it as shown below:

```
#include "global.h"
enum _MY_VARIABLES CurrentValue; //Initializing global variable.
```

Can anyone tell why the EDC is behaving in such manner? I have debugged the code every bit, and even checked in assembly language, but couldn't find the reason.

I know global variable by default gets initialized with `0`, but I want to initialize it with `-1`.

I could also do as below which works fine, but my mind is stucked to find an explanation of the above weird behavior.

```
#include "global.h"
enum _MY_VARIABLES CurrentValue;
CurrentValue = -1; //Initializing global variable.
```

Comment: Note that you should not define names starting with an underscore and followed by a capital letter; they are reserved for use by the implementation unconditionally.  In general, you should avoid leading underscores on names; most of them are reserved for the implementation, but the extra rules are subtle.  That's contrary to many examples.  Note that system headers _are_ part of the implementation so they _are_ supposed to use such names to protect your code.  But that makes them bad exemplars.

Comment: Does `global.h` have a semi-colon after the close brace?  Note that variables with an enumeration type should only have values with are part of the enumeration.  You have names for one, two and three (with values 0, 1, 2 respectively — that could cause confusion), but initialize the variable to a value that is not part of the enumeration.  That's dangerous.  If you want to have `-1` for 'uninitialized', then add the enumeration: `enum MY_VARIABLES { ONE = 1, TWO = 2, THREE = 3, UNINITIALIZED = -1 };` — note that the leading underscores have gone in accordance with my previous comment.'

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for your response. I will try out with your suggestion and post the EDC behavior.